# How to inject CSRFGuard security tokens using jQuery using $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, csrf, csrf-protection

I am using CSRFGuard 3.1.0
I have configured the servlet in web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>JavaScriptServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.servlet.JavaScriptServlet</servlet-class>        
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JavaScriptServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/JavaScriptServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Now I have a JSP file userProfile.jsp 
1) I have configured the script for injecting the tokens like

```
<script src="/JavaScriptServlet"></script>
```

2) Now I include the jQuery script file dedicated for this JSP file

```
<script src="../js/userProfile.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

3) I have text box 1 - for original password
4) I have text box 2 - for new password
5) I have text box 3 - for confirm password
6) I have a change password button which makes AJAX call to the server

```
<button  type="button" name="changePswd" id="changePswd">Change password</button>
```

7) On click of this button a $.ajax (jQuery) function is called which is in  a js file. The function is as below:

```
$("#changePswd").click(
                function() {                    

                    $.ajax({
                            url: location.protocol + "//" +location.host + '/my-project/secure/changePassword.html',

                            data: {
                                username : $('#userName').val(),
                                oldPassword : $('#oldPassword').val(),
                                newPassword : $('#newPassword').val(),
                                retypeNewPassword : $('#retypeNewPassword').val()

                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                $("#dialog").dialog('close');
                                $('#dialog-6').dialog('open');

                                $('#displayResult-6').html(data);
                            },
                            error: function(xhr,status,error) {
                                $('#displayResult').html('�V');
                            }
                })              
                });
```

8) And this call is being blocked by CSRFGuard by saying

WARNING: potential cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack thwarted (user:, ip:10.48.5.88, method:GET, uri:/my-project/secure/changePassword.html,
 error:required token is missing from the request)

And the when the browser load the userProfile.jsp file where the /JavaScriptServlet is expected to inject tokens, the browser is showing me 404 not found for this particular html call

I am using:
JDK 1.6
CSRFGuard 3.1.0
Weblogic 10.3.6 & jQuery-1.7.1-min.js
Please guide me how to inejct these tokens in this AJAX call!!
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make ajax call work you need to do the following steps:

1) On jsp page 
  a. include the tag lib

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_CSRFGuard_Project/Owasp.CsrfGuard.tld" prefix="csrf" %>
```

2) inject the security token name & value in the meta tags like

```
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="<csrf:tokenname/>"/> 
    <meta name="_csrf" content="<csrf:tokenvalue/>"/>
```

3) on the .js page inject this values in the headers like

```
var csrfHeader = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
                    var csrfToken = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
                    var headers = {};
                    headers[csrfHeader] = csrfToken;
    $.ajaxSetup({
  headers: headers
});
```

And your ajax call should pass the test of CSRFGuard :)

4) /JavascriptServlet is not working or sending 404 in its response
but it is not relevent to make the ajax call work

Thanks

Comment: I have impress with yours answer. So can you please have look into this query too if you have time please - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42095851/csrfguard-request-token-does-not-match-page-token.  Thanks in advance.