# CSRFGuard - request token does not match page token & How can generate token per session

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat7, csrf, csrf-protection, owasp

I am trying to incorporate the CSRFGuard library(< org.owasp csrfguard 3.1.0 >) in order to rectify some CSRF vulnerabilities in an application. However after configuring as specified [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRFGuard_3_User_Manual) I am now getting the below message:

[image]

Here I would like to explain scenario when I am getting this message - For suppose my application landing page like this

[image]

And code snippet for this page(HelloWorld.jsp) is

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="csrfguard.tld" prefix="csrf" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script>
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) {
      url = window.location.href;
    }
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
function changePage(form){
 var selectedIndex = form.selectedPage.selectedIndex;
     var selectedValue = form.selectedPage.options[selectedIndex].value;
  var csrftoken = getParameterByName("OWASP_CSRFTOKEN", form.action);
  if (selectedValue == 'A') {
   form.action = "A.html?OWASP_CSRFTOKEN="+csrftoken;
  }
  if (selectedValue == 'LA') {
   form.action = "helloWorld.do?OWASP_CSRFTOKEN="+csrftoken;
  }
  form.submit();
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <h3>Select request page from this dropdown</h3>
 <form name="test" method="post" action="" id="LAP">
  <select name="selectedPage" class="pageSelection" >
          <option  value="LA" selected>Landing Page</option>
          <option  value="A">A page</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" name="adding" value="Go" onClick="changePage(this.form);"/>
  <!--<input type="submit" name="adding" value="submit"/>-->
 </form>
 
</body>
<script src="JavaScriptServlet"></script>
</html>
```

And now I am trying to navigate to page **A.html** using dropdown selection of landing page. The page looks to be

[image]

Now here what I have notice is **new token** is not getting generate to **action** attribute of **form** tag of **A.html** page. The Same token(If we see ***OWASP_CSRFTOKEN=KJZ7-7YXP-DWN5-5NVX-5PB7-TNXG-YLAJ-D2XJ***) whatever has on landing page is getting attach to **action** attribute of **form** tag of **A.html** page. The code snippet of A.html page is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>A page</title>
<script>
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) {
      url = window.location.href;
    }
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
function changePage(form){
 var selectedIndex = form.selectedPage.selectedIndex;
     var selectedValue = form.selectedPage.options[selectedIndex].value;
  var csrftoken = getParameterByName("OWASP_CSRFTOKEN", form.action);
  if (selectedValue == 'A') {
   form.action = "A.html?OWASP_CSRFTOKEN="+csrftoken;
  }
  if (selectedValue == 'LA') {
   form.action = "helloWorld.do?OWASP_CSRFTOKEN="+csrftoken;
  }
  form.submit();
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>A Page</h1>
 <h3>Select request page from this dropdown</h3>
 <form name="test" method="post" action="" id="LAP">
  <select name="selectedPage" class="pageSelection" >
          <option  value="LA">Landing Page</option>
          <option  value="A" selected>A page</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" name="adding" value="Go" onClick="changePage(this.form);"/>
  
 </form>

</body>
<script src="JavaScriptServlet"></script>
</html>
```

Now I am going to **landing page** from **A.html** page by using selection dropdown & again try to reach out **A.html** page by using dropdown selection of landing page then I am getting this error message on tomcat server console

> "WARNING: potential cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack thwarted
>   (user:, ip:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, method:POST,
>   uri:/csrfguard-test-3.1.0-SNAPSHOT/A.html, error:request token does
>   not match page token)"

Here I am unable to understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Please help me as its very important to implement in my actual application & please let me know if any additional information would make it easier to understand. Thanks in advance.

Few other configuration details I am adding as below.
Its my web.xml file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
 <display-name>OWASP CSRFGuard Test</display-name>
 
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
 
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardServletContextListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 
 <filter>
  <filter-name>CSRFGuard</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CSRFGuard</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>JavaScriptServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.servlet.JavaScriptServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>inject-into-attributes</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <!--<init-param>
   <param-name>inject-into-forms</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>-->
  <init-param>
   <param-name>source-file</param-name>
   <param-value>/script/csrfguard.js</param-value>
  </init-param>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>JavaScriptServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/JavaScriptServlet</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <servlet>
  <description></description>
  <display-name>HelloServlet</display-name>
  <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.test.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/HelloServlet</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet
  </servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>config</param-name>
   <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/struts-config.xml
   </param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And its my pom.xml

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com</groupId>
 <artifactId>csrfgaurdapp</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>csrfgaurdapp Maven Webapp</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>3.8.1</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
   <artifactId>csrfguard</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
   <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.10</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
   <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.10</version>
  </dependency>
 
 </dependencies>
 <build>
  <finalName>csrfgaurdapp</finalName>
 </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Where are you getting 'csrftoken' from in your jsp?

Comment: @MohithMaratt: Hi Mohith, the token is generating from this servlet class `org.owasp.csrfguard.servlet.JavaScriptServlet` and this class mapped with this url `/JavaScriptServlet` in `web.xml` file & I am calling 
this servlet from every page of my application like `<script src="JavaScriptServlet"></script>` & you can notice this from my code snippets what I have attached. And I have attached whole
configuration details in my application related with `CSRFGuard` now. Please notice all those, they may be gives better understanding. Thx.

Comment: The hidden element of Page A should contain a new token. Since you got the same token, I guess may be your csrf is not configured correctly or you set it up worongly. You can debug and see in the owasp libraries if the new token is reaching the servlet and rest of the code before getting sent to your page. But the token in the action in page on will get updated only when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

In Owasp.CsrfGuard.properties, set org.owasp.csrfguard.TokenPerPage = false

Reason:

Use of the unique token per page property is currently EXPERIMENTAL,
but provides a significant amount of improved security. Consider the exposure of a CSRF token using the legacy unique per-session model.

Reference: https://github.com/aramrami/OWASP-CSRFGuard/blob/master/csrfguard-test/csrfguard-test-jsp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/Owasp.CsrfGuard.properties